# Facebook api suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have this facebook js api code and it was working till a day back ...
and now it has suddenly stopped working .. 
im using it for a collage project and its possible my partner may have fiddled with it but i cant seem to find anything wrong with it ...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
     var access_token;
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'XYZ', 
        cookie:true, 
        status:true, 
        xfbml:true 
     });

     FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                                login_event();
            });

    function login_event(){
        FB.api("/me",function(user){
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange=function(){
            uid = user.id;
            if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200){
                    $("#middle").load("login_manager.php?uid="+uid);
                }
            }
            request.open("GET", "sessions.php?uid="+uid, true);
            request.send();  

        })
    }

    if(navigator.appCodeName=="Mozilla"){

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

            document.getElementById("middle").innerHTML = "<img src=\"../images/loading-round2.gif\">";
            if (response.session) {
                access_token = response.session.access_token;   
                FB.api('/me', function(user) {  
                   if (user!=null) {
                    var uid = user.id;
                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    request.open("GET", "sessions.php?uid="+uid, true);
                    request.send();           
                    request.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200){
                                $("#middle").load("login_manager.php");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("middle").innerHTML = '<fb:login-button perms="email,user_checkins,offline_access,publish_stream">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>';
                    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('middle'));
                }             
            });

        }



    </script>
```

it does'nt seem to be entering the getLoginStatus() function

Comment: and yes my app id is correct in the actual code ... and none of the facebook examples seem to be working either(i only substituted the app id) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has started working again ..
It was a problem at facebook's end

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your javascript with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or alert statement. Today I tried the following js that is similar to your script and this worked for me:

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>      
    <div id="fb-root"></div>    
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
          FB.init({
              appId: '159618137417054',//enter your app id
              status: true,
              cookie: true,
              xfbml: true
          });
          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
              window.location.reload();
          });
      };
      (function () {
          var e = document.createElement('script');
          e.type = 'text/javascript';
          e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
          e.async = true;
          document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
          alert('FB API Test')
      FB.api('/me', function (response) {
          alert(response.name)
          alert(response.id);//now my facebook ID is available to javascript
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: I have tried both firebug and chromes developer tools..
both dont give me any errors .. i copy pasted your code and its giving me the name and id as "undefined"

Comment: Did you try do a browser refresh when the FB login button changed to "logout"? Does the FB login button display at all and does it change to "logout"? My test you may inspect is here http://niklas-app.appspot.com/user/login I could display a login button, authenticate with facebook and via javascript display my facebook name and id. If the FB login button doesn't change to "logout" then there's a mistake somewhere. I can try the code in the original question to see how it compares.

Comment: thers something additional you need to add to he facebook-button tag for it to change .. 
and i dont want it to change to logout .. in fact i display the users info in place of the button